# Prove existance of positive step size for descent direction

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

How can we prove that there exists positive step size t that quarantiees:
f(x) > f(x + td), if d is descent direction of some cost function 
  f
  :
  
    
      R
    
    n
  
  →
  
    R
  
, such that 
  ∇
  f
  (
  
    x
  
  )
  d<
  0
 >
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, show that $$\nabla f \cdot \mathbf d = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(\mathbf x+t\mathbf d) - f(\mathbf x)}t$$

The limit can only be negative if $f(\mathbf x+t\mathbf d) - f(\mathbf x) < 0$ for small $t$.